# How to Implement to show/hide separate progress indicator / loader for android and iOS in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, api, dart

**How can achieve progress indicator auto show for android ios devices**
**Here the reference image **

[image: Android iOS progress Indicator]

Comment: this has been already built in flutter, and its called `CircularProgressIndicator.adaptive()`

Answer (score 0):

**Automatic show progress dialog for android and iOS**

> Here CircularProgressIndicator() used for android
> CupertinoActivityIndicator() used for iOS

***Sample code***

```
class LoadingDialog extends StatelessWidget {
  static void show(BuildContext context, {Key? key}) => showDialog<void>(
        context: context,
        useRootNavigator: false,
        barrierColor: Colors.white,
        barrierDismissible: false,
        builder: (_) => LoadingDialog(key: key),
      ).then((_) => FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode()));

  static void hide(BuildContext context) => Navigator.pop(context);

  const LoadingDialog({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async => false,
      child: Center(
        child: Platform.isAndroid
            ? const CircularProgressIndicator()
            : CupertinoActivityIndicator(
                color: CColors.green73B66C,
                radius: 20,
                animating: true,
              ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

***We can use here onButtonClick***

```
  TextButton.icon(
      onPressed: (() {
        LoadingDialog.show(context);
        Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5), () {
          LoadingDialog.hide(context);
        });
      }),
      icon: Icon(Icons.phone),
      label: Text("Show Loader"))
```